# Java Module imports

Tags: java, websocket, module

I want to build an application using JS365. The application should be able to act as server and client, depending on what it is the user is doing.
For the server part I need the module javax.websocket.api . For the client part i need javax.websocket.client.api .
But since they are both from the javax.websocket package i get "...reads package javax.websocket from both javax.websocket.client.api and javax.websocket.api"

Do I have to split client and server parts into a module each?
Or is there a way to tell my module-info.java i want to import all packages of javax.websocket?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the [javax.websocket api from 2014](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket) with Java 11 or later if Java 11 includes a [new implementation for websockets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.html)?

Comment: Yeah, i have to use JSR356. It seems it is not by default compatible with Java 9 and up, is it?
The goal would be to have 1 JAR that contains all modules of javax.websocket that i could require in my module-info
I found javax.websocket.all that i can use as a maven dependency, but the module-info doesn't know such a module

Comment: I've downloaded the sources of both modules. The module "javax.websocket-api" contains everything from "javax.websocket-client-api" and additionally some interfaces and annotations that are only used on the server side. IMHO it should be possible to depend only on the "javax.websocket-api" and build a client and/or a server with just this dependency.